# How to save text to speech as a voice recording?

Tags: macos, bash, zsh, text-to-speech, speech

```
say "Hello World"
```

is pretty neato, but it requires the terminal to stay open. Is there a nice way to save the recording from what a "say" would output as a file?

Comment: `man say` might help :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To save to a file use,  the `-o <file name>` option.

```
$ say “Hello World” -o helloworld.aiff
```